# var_dump of PDOStatement Object is not showing returned data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, var-dump

I'm trying to see the structure of the PDOStatement object returned by my query:

```
$sql="SELECT co.CompanyId, co.Name, co.Address, co.City, co.State, ctry.NameEnglish, co.PostalCode FROM company AS co LEFT JOIN country AS ctry ON ctry.CountryId = co.CountryId ORDER BY Name;";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```

The query works, as I'm able to nest some `foreach` statements and display the six rows of data by doing the following.

```
$firstRow=true;
echo '<table>';
foreach ($result as $rowId => $rowData) {
    if ($firstRow) {
        echo "<thead><tr><th>Row Number</th>";
        foreach ($rowData as $fieldId => $fieldData) {
            echo "<th>$fieldId</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr></thead>";
        $firstRow=false;
    }
    echo "<tr><td>$rowId</td>";
    foreach ($rowData as $fieldId => $fieldData) {
        $fieldData=str_replace("\n","<br>",$fieldData);
        echo "<td>$fieldData</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

But I was curious about the internal structure of the object `$result`, so I `var_dump`'ed it and got this:

```
object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) {
    ["queryString"]=>
        string(185) "SELECT co.CompanyId, co.Name, co.Address, co.City, co.State, ctry.NameEnglish, co.PostalCode FROM company AS co LEFT JOIN country AS ctry ON ctry.CountryId = co.CountryId ORDER BY Name;"
}
```

Why doesn't `var_dump` show the arrays associated with the rows and fields?

Comment: Did you do: `$result = $result->fetchAll();` ? and then `var_dump($result);`

Comment: No. I did the two lines in the first code segment and then `var_dump($result);`. I don't use any explicit `fetch`es in the code, even to display the 6 rows.

Comment: According to the docs (http://php.net/PDOStatement), the only propery on a  `PDOStatement` object is `queryString`, as you can see.  It also `implements Traversable`, that's what lets you `foreach` over it.  When you do that, PHP calls methods on the object.  Those methods get the row data.  The rows are not properties of the object, so that's why they don't appear in the `var_dump`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, Rocket. I wonder how, then, am I getting rows and fields in the  `foreach` statements without doing any `fetch`es? I'll post that code.

Comment: @JonathanM: The `fetch` is called internally when you `foreach`.  `PDOStatement ` (it `implements Traversable`) implements the [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.current.php) method to do that.

Comment: Ah, so the proper behavior for a `foreach` is built into the `PDOStatement` object. I see. So there really is additional communication going back to the database during a `foreach`, then, right?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, put that in an answer and let me choose it.

Comment: @JonathanM: Yeah, basically.  I don't know if it's still contacting the database, or if it buffered the full result set in memory.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - You should post your comment as an answer so it doesn't get buried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The manual page for [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/PDOStatement) shows what is going on here.  `PDOStatement` objects only have one *property*, `queryString`.  That's what you're seeing when you `var_dump.`  Everything else on `PDOStatement` is a method, which are excluded from `var_dump`.

`PDOStatement implements Traversable` (Docs for [`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable).)  This is how you are able to see the rows when you `foreach`.  Internally, `PDOStatement` implements methods that are called when you `foreach` over the object.  Those methods call `fetch()` and get the row data.  That's how you see the rows when you `foreach`, but why you can't see them in a `var_dump`.